Which rated voltage is best for replacing these aluminum electrolytic capacitors?
I need to replace two electrolytic capacitors rated for 200V and 330uF. The old ones were CapXon with declared 0.12 of tanδ and 2000 hours at 85°C, belonging to the brand's "cost-effective" GS series.
I looked for replacements with low tanδ (hence lower ESR) and I came across the Nichicon's "high-reliable" UPT series:

It is rated for 5,000 hours at 105° but it's the only declared "high-reliable" series with this low tanδ (as the picture shows, in the 200V and 220V version it has 0.12 max tanδ while other longer-lasting (10,000h or more) series of the same brand have at least 0.20 of tanδ for the corresponding voltage rate).
Now my question is, since both the 200V and the 220V 330uF have same tanδ, is it better if I overrate the original cap to 220V, or is it better if I stick with the original CapXon rate of 200V?
In addition, as seen in this picture taken from the next page of the above datasheet,

consider that both candidates have a diameter of φD 18mm (same as the old 330uF, 200V CapXon capacitors) which is also quite the limit the power board (picture below) can accommodate, but the 200V has a height of L 35.5mm (also in this case exactly like the old CapXon cap) while the 220V is about 5 mm taller.
Given that those extra 5 millimeters of height is not a problem for the board, will the heat, in this latter case, be dissipated on a bigger surface (hence less heat per cm² and lower local temperature), so being also less problematic for the surrounding components (some really near to them seem to have an extra heat protection gum sleeve, as shown in the board pic)?

Which of the two possible candidates (200V or 220V) could have the actual (as opposed to the datasheet rated max) tanδ, given the specific context they are going to operate in (I would guess around or less than 200V*80%=160V)?
Furthermore the 220V version seems to have a slightly higher leakage current (which I don't know if really relevant for my case, because calculated for the 2 different rated voltages), but the 200V and 220V versions have the same rated ripple current, as per the datasheet.
I'm happy to provide more pictures/evidences if needed.
Feel also free to suggest other brand/series cap.
The complete datasheets:

https://www.nichicon.co.jp/english/series_items/catalog_pdf/e-upt.pdf
https://www.capxongroup.com/files/GS_Series.pdf

Thanks a lot for the support.

Note that while tan δ and ESR are related, they are not the same thing. Even a low ESR cap can have high tan δ at high frequencies; this is common in high-κ ceramic capacitors.

@Hearth Thank you for your contribution. Yes indeed. Given a frequency f, ESR is directly proportional to tanδ by the factor 1/(2pif*C). Also I'm specifically interested only in the "aluminum electrolytic capacitors" for my case, a power board. I can also post the complete board picture if useful.

The components with the heatshrink are probably the varistors - these tend to explode so it is common to put thick heatshrink on them and not for heat protection. You seem to be overthinking  the problem - just go with what is available. 200V is fine, 220V probably won’t make much, if any difference. The power supply came out of the factory with cheapy caps, just putting decent quality ones is an upgrade. If you want longer life, then you really need physically larger caps or get a better quality power supply.
